# AlertDialog displays briefly and disappears

Tags: android, operating-system, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an android app written with Xamarin which needs to notify from a class that does not have good access to an activity or context, so I am using a System Alert dialog to display the message.

In Android 4.4, the pop-up appears and the user must tap the OK button to clear it. The rest of the screen is dim and the user cannot interact with any other UI elements until the pop-up is cleared. This is the desired behavior.

In Android 5.0 (tested on a Galaxy S6 and a tablet), the pop-up will appear for about one second and then disappear without requiring any interaction whatsoever. I have done a number of Google and SO searches to no avail.

```
private static void ShowSystemAlert(Context context, string message)
{
    var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialog)
        .SetNeutralButton("OK", (alertSender, args) => {})
        .SetMessage(message)
        .Create();
    dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.Window.SetType(WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
    dialog.Show();
    dialog.Window.DecorView.SetBackgroundResource(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent); //remove strange small border around dialog
}
```

**How can I get the pop-up to work like it does in Android 4.4?** The best answer will work in Lollipop, Marshmallow, and Nougat.

I would also very much appreciate an explanation as to why this happened, or any background information you can give. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it xamarin? Create your alertdialog with just the context, don't use the theme.